# How to access to juju-gui

Tags: juju

I've managed to deploy `juju-gui` in my saucy server via `maas+juju`.

But no matter what I try I cannot log in.

I did:

```
juju set juju-gui password='qwerty'
```

and I even set the user. But I cannot access.

```
# juju show-log
```

Shows error on login.

First.

How can I set the admin-secret is supposed to be used as password.

Second.

If I override the options with the commands above. `Why can't I log in`?

**Thank you.**

Note: This is what it says log:

```
jb4ja:2013-11-23 13:29:48 DEBUG juju.rpc.jsoncodec codec.go:107 <- {"Type":"Admin","Request":"Login","Params":{"AuthTag":"user-admin","Password":"qwerty"},"RequestId":1}
jb4ja:2013-11-23 13:29:48 DEBUG juju.rpc.jsoncodec codec.go:172 -> {"RequestId":1,"Error":"invalid entity name or password","ErrorCode":"unauthorized access","Response":{}}
jb4ja:2013-11-23 13:29:53 DEBUG juju.rpc.jsoncodec codec.go:107 <- {"Type":"Admin","Request":"Login","Params":{"AuthTag":"user-admin","Password":"qwerty"},"RequestId":2}
jb4ja:2013-11-23 13:29:53 DEBUG juju.rpc.jsoncodec codec.go:172 -> {"RequestId":2,"Error":"invalid entity name or password","ErrorCode":"unauthorized access","Response":{}}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `admin-secret` for the environment is in your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` file. This is the password used for the Juju GUI

Comment: Yes! In the local section and in the maas section. admin-secret: 'qwerty'

Comment: And I entered into the configuration of pro of the system and I can see the password set (when I put it by hand with set, because it does not take my environments.yaml password). What's the way to set the hash in the environments.yaml?

Comment: But I forgot to say that's in another machine. So The machine that has the gui app, will not have anything in ~/.juju/environments.yaml Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Officially:

```
juju api-info --password password
```

Or else:

```
grep admin-secret ~/.juju/environments/$(juju env).jenv
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Nice answer :D

Answer (score 0):

For Juju2 as the admin user:

`juju change-user-password admin`

Will let you change the admin user password, much like the root user on a unix system (without knowing the old one).